# Is there a better way than casting a bool into an int for my flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to add an additional parameter to my "student" object for this application I'm working on. Currently, we have hard-coded (I know, bear with me) our is_master_drive value to be set to 1 within the Map<String, dynamic> data structure for the sake of testing through POSTman or what have you. In that same constructor, I am also parsing that boolean value as an integer for the sake of reading it with one of the post request helper methods I wrote. I'm coming across an issue in which the application async threads wig out and the app essentially soft-crashes to the endless "loading" page that we have set up.

From the console:

```
Syncing files to device iPhone 11 Pro...
flutter: Locking to Portrait Mode
flutter: isInitialized: true
Reloaded 20 of 1374 libraries in 1,997ms.
flutter: User Has An Internet Connection
flutter: Data: {success: 1, isMaintenance: false}
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(213)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null
#0      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:53:25)
#1      new Student.fromMap (package:national_driver_training_ed/database.dart:45:25)
#2      StudentDatabase.getStudent.<anonymous closure>     (package:national_driver_training_ed/database.dart:145:24)
#3      new List.generate (dart:core/list.dart:164:28)
#4      StudentDatabase.getStudent     (package:national_driver_training_ed/database.dart:144:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _NationalDriverTrainingAppState.loadPage (package:national_driver_training_ed/main.dart:216:30)<asynchronous suspension> 
#6      _NationalDriverTrainingAppState.build (package:national_driver_training_ed/main.dart:179:19)
#7      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
#9      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/wid<…>
```

And some code:

```
/// Creates a student object from a map of fields that correspond to the student values
Student.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data):
 custid = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID].toString(),
 studentFirst = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME].toString(),
 studentLast = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_LAST_NAME].toString(),
 language = Language.values[int.parse(data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_LANGUAGE])],
 courseType = CourseType.values[data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_COURSE_TYPE]],
 courseState = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_COURSE_STATE].toString(),
 payment = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_PAYMENT].toString(),
 progress = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_PROGRESS].toString(),
 username = data[CustomerInfo.COLUMN_USERNAME].toString(),
 /// WARNING: ALWAYS SET TO 1 FOR TESTING PURPOSES HERE AND IN IS_MASTER_DRIVE.PHP
 isMasterDrive = int.parse(data["is_master_drive"]) == 1
;
```

And the $POST code:

```
/// Return is_master_drive value wrt [student]
Future<String> getIsMasterDrivePOST(Student student) async{
 /// since we're using our REDUNDANT is_master_drive.php page to grab our student info
 var isMasterDriveCheckURL = buildURL(BASE_TEEN_URL, [MOBILE_PATH, LOGIN_PAGE]);
 // var isStateApprovedCheckURL = buildURL(BASE_TEEN_URL, [MOBILE_PATH, IS_STATE_APPROVED_PATH]);
 Map<String, String> args = {CustomerInfo.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID:student.custid};
 // generates our response over to loginUser(Map user, BuildContext context)
 var response = await http.post(isMasterDriveCheckURL, body: args);
 Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
 print(response.body);
 if(data[SUCCESS_TAG] == 1){
   data["is_master_drive"] = 1;
   return data["is_master_drive"];
 } else {
   print("Incorrect Information");
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Why not just stick with int and get rid of the boolean, or write your own parsing function to convert bool to 1/0?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Hmm, that might work. I'll give it a shot as soon as I'm back in the office. Thank you for your input!